# mixing other counters with Perf4J

Tags: java, performance, performancecounter, performance-testing, perf4j

I recently started used [Perf4J](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/) to do performance monitoring of a 3rd party system.
I do this by using the Java API to perform default actions on the system (check in/check out, streaming,etc) and seeing how long they take. However, I'd like to add other counters to the output, for example the number of active sessions on the server. I obviously cannot do this with a StopWatch call.

Any suggestions (using Perf4J or some other technology)?

Thanks

S.